# Converting the following code to higher order function in Scala

Tags: scala

```
lazy val minkowskiHOF: (List[Double], List[Double], Int) => Double = (lstx, listy, p) => {
  var add = lstx.zip(listy) 
                .map(pair => pair._1 - pair._2)
                .foldLeft(0.0)((acumulator,element) => { Math.pow(Math.abs(element), p) +  acumulator })

  Math.pow(add, 1.0 / p)
}
```

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: How to convert the above code to higher order function in scala

Comment: @cgt [Higher-order function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html) takes an ordinary function and produces something. What should your higher-order function do? It should take an ordinary function and produce what? How should it be connected with your `minkowskiHOF`?

Comment: Why do you want to make this "higher order"? If the above code works, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This coded runs and calculates the Minkowski distance properly, but it is not in a higher order function form. I tried to convert the exact same code to use higher order function to calculate the Minkowski distance, but i couldn't.

Comment: What do you understand by "higher order"? If you are trying to turn this into a one-liner, `(l1,l2,p) => Math.pow((l1,l2).zipped.map(_ - _).map(Math.abs).map(Math.pow(_, p)).sum, 1.0 / p)` should do.

Comment: I am a beginner for scala and trying to understand how higher order function works. This is an example i'm trying to apply.

Comment: @cgt It's hard to answer your question since it's not clear what you want your "higher-order function" to do.
This is a function: `val f: A => B = ???` and this is a higher-order function: `val F: (A => B) => C = ???`

Comment: What i need is simply check how the existing function can be changed to higher order function to do the same thing.

Comment: @cgt Why do you think that every function should be changed to higher-order one? Your function takes two lists of doubles and an integer and returns the distance. So we understand what it's supposed to do. Then you ask about higher-order function. A higher-order function takes a function (and maybe something else) and produces something or it takes something and produces a function. How can we help you to implement it if we don't understand what it's supposed to do and you don't tell?

Comment: @cgt For example `val minkowskiHOF1: (Int => Int, List[Double], List[Double], Int) => Double = (f, lstx, listy, p) => minkowskiHOF(lstx, listy, p)` is a higher-order function and does exactly the same as your `minkowskiHOF`. It just ignores functional argument `f`. Are you happy with such higher-order function?

Comment: Thank you Dmytro. This is what i wanted. As i said, i want to test the code in HOF form that's why. I am a new learner.

Answer (score 2):

**cgt**: I have a cup. How do I drive a nail through it?

**everyone**: For what purpose? How should the new cup be different?

**cgt**: It should be exactly the same cup. I want to learn how to use nails.

**Dmytro Mitin**: Glue a nail to the side of your cup. Whenever you use the cup ignore the nail.

**cgt**: Thank you Dmytro. This is what i wanted.

---

So you want to make a higher order function. What is a higher order function? It's a function that receives a function as a passed parameter and/or returns a function as its result. There are a number of ways you might turn `minkowski()` into a higher order function.

One option is to make the `Math.pow()` part a passed parameter.

```
val minkowskiHOF:(List[Double], List[Double], Int, (Double,Double)=>Double) => Double = 
  (lstx, listy, p, op) => {
    val add = lstx.zip(listy)
                  .map(pair => Math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2))
                  .foldLeft(0.0)(_ + op(_, p))
    op(add, 1.0 / p)
  }
```

Now when you call `minkowskiHOF()` with `Math.pow` as the 4th argument you'll get the Minkowski distance, but you can also pass some other `(Double,Double)=>Double` function instead of `Math.pow` and get a different calculation. So now `minkowskiHOF()` isn't a very good name for your function.

Alternatively, you could return a function.

```
val minkowskiHOF: (List[Double], Int) => List[Double] => Double = 
  (listy, p) => lstx => {
    val add = lstx.zip(listy)
                  .map(pair => Math.abs(pair._1 - pair._2))
                  .foldLeft(0.0)(_ + Math.pow(_, p))
    Math.pow(add, 1.0 / p)
  }
```

This `minkowskiHOF()` function does most of the work to calculate a Minkowski distance, but it returns a function that takes a single `List[Double]` to complete the calculation. So, again, `minkowskiHOF()` is perhaps not a completely accurate name.

Conclusion: Higher order functions can be quite a handy tool to have at your disposal but, like a hammer and nail, it's not always appropriate for every job that comes along.

Comment: You made my day :)